# What are the two boot menu options Fedora 23 created on my hard drive?

Tags: boot, fedora-23

I have installed Fedora 23 on an SSD on a Dell Inspiron 1564.  The installation created two options for Fedora 23 OS on the boot menu (`Fedora 4.2.3 -300 fc23 OS` and `Fedora 0 rescue 23`).  How do I boot directly to the OS as I do not want to see these two options?

I'm a new user to LINUX and do not know much about it.

Comment: You've asked multiple questions as one.  Please split them.

Comment: How to split them? But they all belong to same OS.

Comment: Now I have edited the question. Please give me answer for this.

Comment: Are you booting a live session (from a DVD or flash drive), or have you installed Fedora on your hard drive?  Live sessions will contain those kinds of options, and you can't change them, but they aren't designed to operate from.  If you've installed it on your hard disk, the rescue version is like the Windows recovery partition; it's to recover Fedora if something corrupts it.  It will appear briefly in the GRUB boot menu, but in a few seconds, it should boot into the "real" Fedora.

Comment: I have installed fedora 23 on SSD on Dell Inspiron 1564. I have made three partitions namely: Root, SWAP & Home. Can I give rescue option & directly boot to login screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42003/discussion-between-fixer1234-and-amandeep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Why are there two boot menu options in Fedora 23?

The two boot entries are different.  The first is the actual OS, which is what you would normally use.  The second is a rescue mode in case Fedora gets damaged.

Many Linux distributions include a boot menu entry for a rescue or recovery mode as a means of giving you access to it.  When you get more experienced with Linux, you can pursue editing the GRUB menu if you really want to change it.  However, GRUB typically displays the boot menu options for a few seconds to give you an opportunity to make a selection, and then automatically uses the default choice (usually the first entry), which will be the Fedora OS.  If you want to shave seconds off the startup, you can manually click on it.

On Fedora, it looks like selecting rescue mode actual boots off something other than the system drive:

> #### Booting into Rescue Mode
>
> Rescue mode provides the ability to boot a small Fedora environment entirely from CD-ROM, or some other boot
> method, instead of the system's hard drive. As the name implies,
> rescue mode is provided to rescue you from something. During normal
> operation, your Fedora system uses files located on your system's hard
> drive to do everything — run programs, store your files, and more.
>
> However, there may be times when you are unable to get Fedora running
> completely enough to access files on your system's hard drive. Using
> rescue mode, you can access the files stored on your system's hard
> drive, even if you cannot actually run Fedora from that hard drive.
>
> To boot into rescue mode, you must be able to boot the system using
> one of the following methods:
>
> - By booting the system from an installation boot CD-ROM or DVD.
> - By booting the system from other installation boot media, such as USB flash devices.
> - By booting the system from the Fedora CD-ROM #1 or DVD.

Source and detailed instructions: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-boot.html

If the installation did not include creating a rescue CD, that facility is likely included on the live session you created from the ISO, which you used to install Fedora (probably a DVD or flash drive).  So selecting rescue mode from the boot menu will probably instruct you to load that.  To ensure that you're prepared for an emergency, just select that from the boot menu one time to see what instructions you get and to verify that you have the necessary media.